# Order of hats in the user profile popup

Tags: discussion, profile-page, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

I'm struggling to understand the order the hats are featured in the user profile:

[image]

- It's not the same order they appear in the Winter Bash homepage:

[image]

- It's not the order you earned them - Hedy Lamarr is the last hat I earned but it appears second in my profile
- It's not alphabetical - Heddy Lamarr appears before Albert Einstein
- It's not the number of sites you earned the hat on - I have Albert Einstein on two sites (SO and SU), but Tourist only on one (Security SE)

I refuse to believe SE devs just forgot the `order by` clause there...

Comment: Well, it was asked before and I really doubt it changed since then, so closing as duplicate. It's years old mystery.